# Select all elements that does not exist in another node with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to select all elements that does not exist in another node.

```
<root>
  <users>
    <array>
      <name>John</name>
      <age>30</age>
    </array>
    <array>
      <name>Joe</name>
      <age>30</age>
    </array>
    <array>
      <name>Lou</name>
      <age>30</age>
    </array>
  </users>
  <selected_users>
    <name>Joe</name>
    <age>30</age>
  </selected_users>
</root>
```

So what I want from this list is John and Lou since their not listed under the selected users node..

Comment: I modified your code to make it well-formed. Please edit it if it's no longer accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is a short and simple way to do this:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="users/array/name[not(.=/*/selected_users/name)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <users>
        <array>
            <name>John</name>
            <age>30</age>
        </array>
        <array>
            <name>Joe</name>
            <age>30</age>
        </array>
        <array>
            <name>Lou</name>
            <age>30</age>
        </array>
    </users>
    <selected_users>
        <name>Joe</name>
        <age>30</age>
    </selected_users>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
John Lou
```

**Note**:

If you want to get the wanted `name` elements in a variable, use:

```
    <xsl:variable name="vSomeName" select=
"/*/users/array/name[not(.=/*/selected_users/name)]"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this xpath:

`/*/users/array/name[not(.=/*/selected_users/name)]`

to get "John" and "Lou". I can add an XSLT example if you specify what kind of output you're trying to get.

Comment: hmm.. I just want the name.. So Im thinking something like this:
<xsl:for-each select="???">
   <xsl:value-of select="name" />
</xsl:for-each>

Comment: @DevNull: `xsl:value-of` outputs the string value only of the first node in the node-set, specified in the `select` attribute. And your code actually (due to this) produces only `John"

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - You are absolutely right. I swore I tested this before I posted. I'm going to remove the example entirely.

Comment: @DevNull: Don't worry -- it's human to err. Of course, the XPath expression itself is correct.